# ¿Por qué los campos de mi formulario no se envían al servidor?

Tags: php, formularios

Mi HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<form action="enviarcorreo.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="position:relative">
            <input type="text" name="Nombre" data-new-placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Nombre"required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Email"required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="Telefono" class="form-control label_better" placeholder="Telefono"required>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Mi PHP:

```
<?php 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$telefono = $_POST['telefono']; 

$header = 'From: ' . $email . " \r\n"; 
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n"; 
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain"; 

$mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por  " . $nombre . ", telefono: " . $telefono . " \r\n"; 
$mensaje .= "Su e-mail : " . $email . " \r\n"; 
$mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n"; 
$mensaje .= "Fue enviado... " . date('d/m/Y', time()); 

$para = "stestebenlucas@gmail.com"; 
$asunto = 'ASUNTO DEL MENSAJE'; 


mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);
?>
```

Entonces lo que ocurre es que me llega el mail pero sin datos.

Comment: Te recomiendo que realices el [tour] y puedas comprender como funciona el sitio. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta. ¿Esta bien que tengas doble formulario (`form`)? ¿De qué manera realizas el SUBMIT de tu formulario? ¿Sólo el valor de `$_POST['email']` llega como nulo?

Answer (score 3):

Las etiquetas `input` en el atributo `name` están con la primera letra en mayúscula y en el `$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];` está con minúscula.
Por otro lado, no es correcto meter un formulario dentro de otro ya que puede confundir cual de los dos se debe enviar.

Answer (score 2):

El problema se encuentra en el `name` de tus input, estas enviando `Nombre`, pero los recoges `$_POST['nombre']`, no son iguales ya que uno posee mayuscula y otro no. Tendrian que ser igual tanto en mayusculas como minusculas.

Tambien estas utilizando 2 `form` lo cual no es recomendable, y el segundo no lo estas cerrando

Answer (score 0):

Simple, el name en tus inputs tiene la primera letra mayúscula y cuando haces el $_POST los estás poniendo con minúscula, es por eso que cuando te llega el mail esta vacío, no hay valor asignado para esas variables.

Yo te recomendaría que usaras una función, puedes poner un input type=“submit” y cuando lo recibas usar un isset($_POST[‘submit’]) 
Por otro lado la clase de bootstrap para el formulario horizontal debes de ponerlo en el form de abajo  así evitarás tener 1 form dentro de otro

Saludos